# Как получить текст без тегов из Action в TestCase TFS Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, tfs

При извлечении имени Action из TestCase я получаю это:

```
"{TestStep id=2 title=<DIV><P>Запустить приложение.</P></DIV>}".
```

Мне нужно извлечь только: "Запустить приложение.". Я использовал парсинг строки. Возможно ли извлечь без парсинга.

Answer (score 0):

Да тест-кесы так выглядят. Есть статья, где эта проблема расссматривается. Возможно она будет полезна:

[How to use Test Step using REST Client Helper?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/how-to-use-test-step-using-rest-client-helper/)